# How to install strapi?

Tags: strapi

I checked to see if I have both nodejs and npm latest version and I do so not sure what I am doing wrong.

PS C:\Users\Joseph Osorio\Joseph.dev\1 Website - Projects\strapi> npx create-strapi-app my-project --quickstart

> > 

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Joseph'
command not found: create-strapi-app
PS C:\Users\Joseph Osorio\Joseph.dev\1 Website - Projects\strapi>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up answering this question on the Strapi forums but will answer here as well in case anyone else runs into this.

Strapi does not like directories with spaces in them, changing his directory names solved the issue.